# Spacing between text under picture

Tags: text, pspicture

Hei guys!

I got two pictures beside eachother, and I need to separate the text under the pictures.

Any tips?

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{figure}[hbp]   
\centering   
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}   
  \centering   
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{Bilder/Diskusjon/DensitetTrykk1.PNG}     
  \caption{Sammenheng mellom densitet og trykkfasthet i R-1.0.}
  \label{fig:DensitetTrykk1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{Bilder/Diskusjon/DensitetTrykk2.PNG}
  \caption{Sammenheng mellom densitet og trykkfasthet i R-1.1.}
  \label{fig:DensitetTrykk2}  
\end{minipage}  
\end{figure}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need a minimal working example to play with. Is there a `\columnsep` command involved?

Comment: `\hfill` between the minipages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

similar question has been asked many, many time ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hbp]
    \captionsetup{justification=justified}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%Bilder/Diskusjon/DensitetTrykk1.PNG
  \caption{Sammenheng mellom densitet og trykkfasthet i R-1.0.}
  \label{fig:DensitetTrykk1}
\end{minipage}\hfil
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}%Bilder/Diskusjon/DensitetTrykk2.PNG
  \caption{Sammenheng mellom densitet og trykkfasthet i R-1.1.}
  \label{fig:DensitetTrykk2}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `floatrow` package is done for that:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, demo]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{floatrow, graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbp]
\floatsetup{ floatrowsep=qquad}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[1.2\FBwidth]{\caption{Sammenheng mellom densitet og trykkfasthet i R-1.0.}
  \label{fig:DensitetTrykk1}}
 {\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Bilder/Diskusjon/DensitetTrykk1.PNG}}
%
\ffigbox[1.2\FBwidth]{\caption{Sammenheng mellom densitet og trykkfasthet i R-1.1.}
  \label{fig:DensitetTrykk2}}
  {\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Bilder/Diskusjon/DensitetTrykk2.PNG}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]